# How to make Sorting Visualizer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make sorting visualizer using react, I also made algorithms ready for different sort mechanism like merge sort, bubble sort, insertion sort and Quick sort but not able to implement it visually.

I made visualizer for bubble sort but for that too I asked question in stack overflow and one of the guys gave the entire logic of it using react, now I am trying to make it possible for merge sort, spend 4 days to implement it but still I got stuck, it feels like I will not able survive without taking any help.

Can anyone please suggest me what to do?

my App.js file

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [arrayForSort, setArrayForSort] = useState([
    70,
    20,
    40,
    90,
    26,
    10,
    80,
    50
  ]);

  const [isSort, setIsSort] = useState(false);

  const fetchArray = arrayForSort.map((element) => {
    return (
      <span className="array-element" key={element}>
        {element}
      </span>
    );
  });

  const beginSort = () => {
    setIsSort(true);
  };

  const mergeSort = (myArray) => {
    let newArray = [...myArray];

    // if array contains nothing or only one element then return the array
    if (myArray.length <= 1) return myArray;

    // find the middle of the array
    const middle = Math.floor(myArray.length / 2);

    // Split the array into two
    const leftArray = myArray.slice(0, middle);
    const rightArray = myArray.slice(middle);

    // recursive function to combine left and right array
    return merge(mergeSort(leftArray), mergeSort(rightArray), newArray);
  };

  const merge = (leftArr, rightArr, originalArray) => {
    let resultArray = [],
      leftIndex = 0,
      rightIndex = 0;

    while (leftIndex < leftArr.length && rightIndex < rightArr.length) {
      if (leftArr[leftIndex] < rightArr[rightIndex]) {
        let newLeftIndex = originalArray.indexOf(leftArr[leftIndex]);
        let newRightIndex = originalArray.indexOf(rightArr[rightIndex]);
        [originalArray[newLeftIndex], originalArray[newRightIndex]] = [
          originalArray[newRightIndex],
          originalArray[newLeftIndex]
        ];
        resultArray.push(leftArr[leftIndex]);
        leftIndex++;
      } else {
        let newLeftIndex = originalArray.indexOf(leftArr[leftIndex]);
        let newRightIndex = originalArray.indexOf(rightArr[rightIndex]);
        [originalArray[newRightIndex], originalArray[newLeftIndex]] = [
          originalArray[newLeftIndex],
          originalArray[newRightIndex]
        ];
        resultArray.push(rightArr[rightIndex]);
        rightIndex++;
      }
    }

    setArrayForSort(originalArray);

    resultArray = resultArray
      .concat(leftArr.slice(leftIndex))
      .concat(rightArr.slice(rightIndex));

    return resultArray;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSort) {
      const arr = [...arrayForSort];
      const sortedArray = mergeSort(arr);
      console.log(sortedArray);
      // setArrayForSort(sortedArray);
      setIsSort(false);
    }
  }, [arrayForSort, setArrayForSort, isSort, mergeSort]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Merge Sort</h1>
      <div className="array">{fetchArray}</div>
      <button onClick={beginSort}>SORT</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you pin-point the exact problem with your current code ? Also a codesandbox link for something as big as this code would fasten solving your problem.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur The problem is that I can make the algorithm and it does sort the array but it sort it in one shot, I am not able to keep track of every sort step happening.
Link for CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/merge-sort-gdidc?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually trickier than I originally thought it was going to be. I wanted each individual "swap" the merge sort detected to be displayed, but I'm having problems going "back up the splits" correctly with my original idea.

I'll probably revisit this, but in case I don't, here's a version that just slightly tweaks your original code. You'll notice the bigger splits just sort of "snap" into being in the correct order, which probably isn't what you want, but hopefully it helps with understanding Timeouts and Promises:

https://codesandbox.io/s/merge-sort-forked-coh7r?file=/src/App.js

Just to be clear, everything is still basically happening in "one shot", meaning the call stack is still pretty much identical, meaning all the functions are still being called right on top of each other. The difference is that the `Promise/setTimeout` is adding a "pause here then run this" and the `async/await` is adding a "wait for that before continuing". I think if you really wanted to show off "each swap" you would have to really break up the control flow and add in some conditional steps.

Comment: This actually looks good to me, at least it works lot better than that of my broken code. But, yes, you are right , if it has to show each swap, there should be some conditional steps. Also, while working on this I got an another approach that, first sort the array in one shot, and store all the changes in an another array and then show the changes as per needed but I don't know if it would be good practice to store all the changes in an additional array then show the changes on UI.

Comment: @Siddhesh If you're talking about your original code, it wasn't broken at all, very solid implementation only like "kinda big thing" was that you could replace the bulky while loop with a `.sort()` (I tweaked the linked code to show how that could be accomplished). As for the "extra array", I think that sounds perfectly fine. There might be a better way to do it, but this is the kind of thing where, you'll think about it again 6 months from now and come up with code that's 10x better. If you got it to work and learned something, that's more than great!